# A service for storing info (notes, links) for future is needed

Tags: note-taking, memory-management

Desired features:

- Chronological notes (like blog)
- Private and public notes (customized access would be a plus)
- Rich note (at least must support hyperlinks)
- Supports links to single notes (including private)
- Tags
- Easy way to create a note while browsing (Firefox, Chrome)
- Easy way to create a note on Android (including images)
- Easy searching

Comment: Something like [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) might work? Or are you looking for a different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Evernote](https://evernote.com/):

- Chronological notes (like blog) **Yes**
- [Private and public notes](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/sharing.php) (customized access would be a plus) **Yes**
- Rich note (at least must support hyperlinks) **Yes**
- [Supports links to single notes (including private)](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/sharing.php) **Yes**
- Tags **Yes**
- Easy way to create a note while browsing (firefox, chrome) **Yes, Chrome only, Firefox add-on is not up-to-dated**
- Easy way to create a note on android (including images) **Yes**
- Easy Searching **Yes**

The links in the second and fourth bullet are the same. I don't know if it is posible to have customized access. If you need that feature, I suggest you take note in Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Now, 4 years later, I would recommend using [OneNote](https://www.onenote.com/download) instead. It and [Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) are my absolute recommendations for note-taking.